How to compute this ratio?
$$\operatorname{S}_t=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{2^r}{t^{2^r}+1}$$
I came across an equation and I was asked to find out $$\operatorname{S}_7:\operatorname{S}_{17}$$
But I was unable to apply any standard limits or squeze play theorem. Neither I was able to convert the summation to definite integral as the limit. Any help is appreciated.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: telescope using$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^2-1}.$$

Thanks @J.G.
Can you please enlighten us how you got this idea and this partial fraction ??

Incrementing $r$ squares $t^{2^r}$, so it makes sense to compare $1/(x-a)$ with $1/(x^2-a)$, but unless $a^2=a$ that doesn't let you use partial fractions.

Taking help from @J.G. comment,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^r}{t^{2^r}+1}&=2^r\left(\frac{1}{t^{2^r}-1}-\frac{2}{t^{2^{r+1}}-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{2^r}{t^{2^r}-1}-\frac{2^{r+1}}{t^{2^{r+1}}-1}
\end{align}$$
So on telescoping you will get
$$\operatorname{S}_t=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{2}{t^{2}-1}-\frac{2^n}{t^{2^n}-1}$$
the right most term will be zero on applying limits and hence you can get $\operatorname{S}_t$ just as a simple function of $t$. From there you can calculate the ratio which is coming as:
$$\frac{\operatorname{S}_7}{\operatorname{S}_{17}}=6$$

$S_t$ should be $\frac{2}{t^2-1}$, not $\frac{2}{t^2+1}$. You did get the correct ratio so I suspect this is just a typographical error.

Done, error removed.
